# PHP: Converting a number to an array of digits

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, zero

I'm trying to convert a number to an array of digits. The code is very simple.

```
function number_to_array($number) {
    $number = (string) $number;
    $array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($number); $i++) {
        $array[] = $number[$i];
    }
    return $array;
}
```

It works great except when you pass it a number that starts with `0`. If I pass this method `00`, it only returns `[0]`. If I pass it `01`, it only returns `[1]`. I have tried everything and not being able to fix this problem. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Do not start numbers with 0. Unless number is smaller than 1.

Comment: Are you passing an integer argument? You cannot, by definition, have leading zeroes in an integer. They will always be lost when the expression (integer) is evaluated.

Comment: It will work if you pass in the number as a string to that function. An integer can't start with a zero (since `012` is equal to `12`).

Comment: If you want to shrink this down, you might want to look at `preg_split`, you could do something like `preg_split("//", $number, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php